# Delete Cookies message in Blogger's Mobile Custom view

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have the following problem (European issue). I want to delete the standard Cookies message Google has added to all Blogger templates. I managed to do this by inserting the following HTML text under Header:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> cookieChoices = {}; </script>
```

If you open the blog on a DESKTOP, this indeed hides the message. Perfect. However, on the MOBILE, this HTML is not picked up. What I already did is selecting the CUSTOM view. I then somewhere in the HTML need to include something. I know this "something" makes use of the Mobile on/off like this:

```
<b:widget id='Attribution1' locked='true' mobile='no' title='' type='Attribution'/>
```

I have however no idea what EXACTLY and where EXACTLY. It would be great if somebody can solve this mystery for me!

Thanks in advance,
Arnoud (NL)

BTW, sorry if this is already answered somewhere, I could not find it.

Comment: Ever tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This link allows you to somewhat customize (and seemingly replace too) the EU cookie message: [STCnetwork.org](http://www.stcnetwork.org/)

Or you can play around with the code below.

You can choose button's color, outside of button's text color, background color, shadow, and text size.

How did it go?

```
<!--Custom EU Cookies Notice by STCnetwork.org--> 
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  cookieOptions = { 
    msg: &quot;This site uses cookies!&quot;, 
    link: &quot;https://www.blogger.com/go/blogspot-cookies&quot;, 
    close: &quot;Got it!&quot;, 
    learn: &quot;Learn More&quot; }; 
</script> 
    <style>
.cookie-choices-info {
z-index:0000ff!important;
background-color:#0000ff!important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0000ff;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #000!important;
padding:3px 0px!important;
}
.cookie-choices-text {
font-size:30px !important;
color:#ffffff!important;
}
.cookie-choices-info {
font-size:30px !important;
background-color: #0000ff!important;
color: #0000ff;
border-radius: 1px!important;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #000!important;
padding:6px!important;
text-transform: none!important;
}
.cookie-choices-button {
background-color: #0000ff!important;
color: #0000ff;
border-radius: 1px!important;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #000!important;
padding:6px!important;
text-transform: none!important;
}
</style>
```